# Tomcat не хочет загружать Java проект

Tags: java, tomcat

Возникла проблема с Tomcat. Он не хочет загружать Maven проект и в логах выдает такую ошибку:

```
...deployment descriptor [E:\apache-tomcat-9.0.7\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml] has been ignored.
```

В дескрипторе указал такой путь к проекту

```
<Context path="" docBase="E:\JAVA EE\ishopV2\src\main\webapp" reloadable="true"/>
```

Проект вроде как находит, но не загружает.
Буду очень благодарен, если кто-то знает как это решить.

---

[image: Серверный Лог]

Так же пробовал ставить другие версии Tomcat. Проблема оставалась такой-же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо исправить путь в `docBase`, чтобы работало, т.к. Tomcat не понимает обратный слэш, его надо заменить на прямой.

```
<Context path="" docBase="E:/JAVA EE/ishopV2/src/main/webapp" reloadable="true"/>
```

Comment: к сожалению это не помогло(

Comment: тогда поудаляйте все из webapps

Comment: имеется в виду папка в томкате?если да,тогда это тоже не помогает

Comment: можете сбросить серверный лог запуска сервера?

Comment: Скинул,посмотрите ниже.

Comment: это не весь лог, к тому же нужно постить в текстовом виде. по логу лишь видно что ваше приложение не работает. причина опять-таки не известна. вы никогда не сможете загрузить неработающее приложение.