# Коррекция URL стартовой страницы в Tomcat

Tags: java, веб-программирование, intellij-idea, tomcat

Встал вопрос, при вот таких настройках Tomcat, я все равно обращаюсь к сайту через

```
http://localhost:1488/Server_exploded_war/
```

т.е. стартовой страницей является не

```
localhost:1488/
```

а указанное выше. Подскажите, если знаете, в чем моя ошибка.

**Настройки:**
[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому, что вы запускаете Tomcat через IJ. Там у вас на второй вкладке устанавливается контекст приложения. Если он не установлен, то по умолчанию им является название папки, куда выкладываются файлы приложения. Чтобы понять как устроен сервер Tomcat, нужно читать [документацию](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/). Виртуальные директории парятся в [дескрипторе сервера `context.xml`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html).

> Элемент Context представляет веб-приложение, которое запускается на определенном виртуальном хосте.  Каждое веб-приложение основано на файле архива веб-приложений (WAR) или соответствующем каталоге, содержащем соответствующее распакованное содержимое, как описано в Спецификации сервлета (версия 2.2 или более поздняя).  Для получения дополнительных сведений об архивах веб-приложений вы можете загрузить спецификацию сервлетов и просмотреть Руководство разработчика приложений Tomcat.
>
> Веб-приложение, используемое для обработки каждого HTTP-запроса, выбирается Catalina на основе сопоставления самого длинного префикса URI запроса с путем контекста каждого определенного контекста.  После выбора этот контекст выберет соответствующий сервлет для обработки входящего запроса в соответствии с отображениями сервлетов, определенными развертыванием веб-приложения.
>
> Вы можете определить столько элементов контекста, сколько захотите.  Каждый такой контекст ДОЛЖЕН иметь уникальное имя контекста на виртуальном хосте.  Путь контекста не обязательно должен быть уникальным (см. Параллельное развертывание ниже).  Кроме того, должен присутствовать контекст с контекстным путем, равным строке нулевой длины.  Этот контекст становится веб-приложением по умолчанию для этого виртуального хоста и используется для обработки всех запросов, которые не соответствуют пути контекста другого контекста.

Как например в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/814175/204920) ответе.